# Libtorrent settings enum

Tags: c++, enums, libtorrent

In Libtorrent sessions there is a few enurm, I'm a bit stuck on how to set the enurm for instance in the following:

```
   struct session_settings
    {
       enum suggest_mode_t
       {
          no_piece_suggestions,
          suggest_read_cache,
       };
    }
```

**no_piece_suggestions** is **0** and **suggest_read_cache** is **1** with **no_piece_suggestions** being the default so how would I make **suggest_read_cache** the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default just means what the setting will be if you don't set it.

If you want to change the default, you change the libtorrent source file src/session.cpp (where the session_settings constructor is defined).

If you just want to change the settings for your session object, construct a session_settings object, set session_settings::suggest_mode to session_settings::suggest_read_cache then call session::set_settings() with your settings object.